Что такое объяснение?
Предложение 34 содержит объяснение того, о чём говорится в
предложении 33.

(33)Сходите домой, принесите шесть копеек, тогда и лекарства
полу́чите! (34)Свойкин вышел из аптеки и отправился к себе домой.

Почему неверен вариант? Ведь он отправился домой потому, что нужны были лекарства. Это ли не объяснение?

Немного скорректирую: *вернулся домой без лекарств, но за деньгами для лекарств),
потому что нужны были деньги, о которых говорится в 33.
То есть у вас есть таки неточность:
вернулся он домой не потому, что нужны лекарства,
а потому что оказалось, что нужны деньги о которых он узнал в 33.
А за лекарствами он пойдет опять в больницу, но уже с деньгами. То есть ошибка всё таки есть, вы не заменили слово "лекарство" на "деньги на лекарства". В общем, кажется, что ерунда, но на самом деле эти логические моменты, несмотря на простоту, далеко не всегда очевидны.
То есть:
"Ведь он отправился домой потому, что нужны были лекарства." - не достаточно точно.
Сравните с:
Он отправился домой(34) потому, что оказалось(33): на лекарства нужны деньги.
То есть, предложение 33 содержит объяснение того, о чём говорится в 34. - ВЕРНО.
Предложение 34 содержит объяснение того, о чём говорится в 33. - НЕ ВЕРНО.
